# BTRFS - Check if any operation is running

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs

So, I have a BTRFS drive that is currently running a replace operation to move data from one drive in the RAID array to another, using the built-in BTRFS volume raid tools. After the replace finishes, I have more operations to run. How can I check if the replace is running in a while loop, or if any other operation is running in a while loop?

Comment: Not tested, therefore just a comment. `man btrfs-replace` mentions the `-B` option for `start`, the description is "no background replace". So I expect `btrfs replace start -B …` to exit only after the operation finishes. If I'm right, this makes it suitable for scripts where you want to run the next command not too soon. No need for checking in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using `sudo btrfs replace status /path/to/mountpoint`.

---

This script will run the command to check if the operation is still ongoing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MOUNTPOINT="/path/to/mountpoint"
NEXT_OPERATION="sudo <some other command>"

while true; do
  status=$(sudo btrfs replace status $MOUNTPOINT)
  if [[ $status == "replace is done" ]]; then
    echo "Replace is done, running next operation..."
    $NEXT_OPERATION
    break
  fi
  sleep 60  # Wait 60 seconds before checking again
done
```

Please note that you should know what the exit status of the competed operation is, and substitute `"replace is done"` with the relevant output from `sudo btrfs replace status /path/to/mountpoint`. I just phrased it that way because I honestly have no idea what it actually echoes.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to check until it succeeds, and then run the next operation?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: In my Kubuntu `man btrfs-replace` mentions the `-1` option for `status`. The description is "print once instead of print continuously until the replace operation finishes (or is cancelled)".  This makes me think the command *without* `-1` runs until the replace operation finishes and there is absolutely no need for a loop. I haven't tested, but *if I'm right* then it means you have reinvented the wheel using the wheel we already have.